# Safari Cross Site Ajax call does not store cookie

Tags: vue.js, cookies, safari, cross-site

I have a website on VueJS and a backend on AWS.

Lets say the website is on [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), on a hosting server with CPanel and my backend on aws runs under [www.mybackend.com](http://www.mybackend.com)

When the user logs in using the website, it makes an axios/fetch call to the backend. The backend will return a set-cookie for the [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) domain.

Although Chrome and FF works fine. Safari does not store the cookie as it is a cross site cookie.

Is there any easy way to make Safari store the cookie and send it to the calls to the backend? Can I mask the backend url with a subdomain from my main domain? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does behave differently from those other browsers. It will only allow cross-origin cookies if they are from the same cookie domain.

So you can get this to work but only if you're in a position to change the URL so that the domains match.

So if you have a website at:

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

and the backend at:

```
backend.mywebsite.com
```

You can then share the cookie by setting the `Domain`:

`Set-Cookie: my-cookie=value; Domain=mywebsite.com`

If the two sites are on totally unrelated domains and you can't change that then I'm not aware of any way to make that work with Safari.

I did a more complete write-up of using cookies with CORS (including the quirks with Safari) at https://cors-errors.info/faq#cdc8